# Java JSP Mysql error

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp

I have a simple web page when if someone book a room than he can delete the reservation.
I have in my DB a schema called: hotel_booking with this value:

> (id primary key)cid,(id)resid,(String)cname,(String)email,(String)arrival_date,(String)departure_date,(int)person,(int)room,(String)type_room,(Text)comment, (int)status

i have this code:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>

<% 
String id = request.getParameter("resid");
int dlt=0;
if (dlt!=0)
dlt =Integer.parseInt(id);



    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/HotelReservation","root" ,"123456789");

    Statement st = con.createStatement();;  

    int i = st.executeUpdate("delete from hotel_booking where resid=" +dlt+"");
    if (i != 0) {
        response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
    } else {
        out.print("Data not deleted successfully");
    }
%>
```

for the cancel.jsp page.

and this is the code of booked.jsp

```
<%-- 
    Document   : index
    Created on : Feb 27, 2015, 7:39:57 PM
    Author     : OOPs
--%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">
         <title>JSP Page</title>


<link href="responsiveslides.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="themes.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="responsiveslides.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>your booked detail</h1>
         <%


       try{
            String n=(String)session.getAttribute("sessname");         

       // out.print("Hello "+n);
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       // out.println("driver loaded");
     Connection  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/HotelReservation","root" ,"123456789");
      //  out.println("Connect");
      Statement  st =  con.createStatement();
      //    out.println("conncetion successfull");


       ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from hotel_booking where uid = "+n);

       %>


        <%  while(rs.next())
        {

            int id = rs.getInt("cid");
            int res = rs.getInt("resid");
          //  out.println(id);
            String cname  = rs.getString("cname");
           // out.println(cname);
            String email  = rs.getString("email");
            String arrival  = rs.getString("arrival_date");
            String departure  = rs.getString("departure_date");
            int person  = rs.getInt("person");
            int room  = rs.getInt("room");
            String type_room = rs.getString("type_room");



            %> 

            <div class="hotel-block"  style="background-color: #5882FA;padding: 2px 15px 30px;margin-top: -20px; width: 102%; margin-left: -23px;">
                ...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
                <h2 class="heading"><label style=" margin-left: 150px; margin-top: 151px;">Name :</label><span  style=" margin-left: 200px;"><%out.println(cname);%></h2> 
                <h2 class="heading"><label style="margin-left: 150px;">Email :</label><span  style=" margin-left: 200px;"><%out.println(email);%></span></h3> 
                <h2 class="heading"><label style="margin-left: 150px;">arrival date :</label><span  style=" margin-left: 100px;"><%out.println(arrival);%></h2>
                <h2 class="heading"><label style="margin-left: 150px;">departure date:</label><span  style=" margin-left: 50px;"><%out.println(departure);%></h2> 
                <h2 class="heading"><label style="margin-left: 150px;">no. of person :</label><span  style=" margin-left: 70px;"><%out.println(person);%></h2>
                <h2 class="heading"><label style="margin-left: 150px;">no. of room :</label><span  style=" margin-left: 100px;"><%out.println(room);%></h2> 
                <h2 class="heading"><label style="margin-left: 150px;">type room:</label><span  style=" margin-left: 100px;"><%out.println(type_room);%></h2>

               <form action='cancel.jsp'>
             <input type='submit' name='cancel' value='Cancel Reservation'>
             <input type="hidden" name="res" value=<%= res %>>
            </form>
           </div>



           <% } }

            catch(Exception e)
                    {

                    }
            out.close();

            %>
    </body>
</html>
```

if I try to cancel my reservation I take this error:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

Message An exception occurred processing [/cancel.jsp] at line [8]

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing [/cancel.jsp] at line [8]

5: <% 
6: String id = request.getParameter("resid");
7: int dlt;
8: dlt =Integer.parseInt(id);
9: 
10:    
11:     


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:593)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:482)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542)
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    org.apache.jsp.cancel_jsp._jspService(cancel_jsp.java:125)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:444)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

How can I solve this problem? Thank you for your help!

Comment: As the error says you never give it the parameter `id` so it can’t convert a nonexistent value to an integer

Comment: So can i do in your opinion? Should i delete string id?

Comment: as the exception is numberformat, the core problem is that, the parameter resid is passed "null" which ultimately can not be converted to int. Try to check the passed parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, that you have defined a hidden-field named `res` but are accessing it as `resid`. Change `String id = request.getParameter("resid");` to `String id = request.getParameter("res");` and it should work.

And as Sazzadur Rahaman mentioned: **Never ever append parameters this way**. Use a `PreparedStatement`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now when I using String id = request.getParameter("res"); the browser shows me 
> Data not deleted successfully

Answer (score 0):

What is the specific request you send to the server? It should have a `resid` appended to it, e.g., `?resid=<number>`.

It looks like `request.getParameter("resid")` is returning `null` in your following line,

```
String id = request.getParameter("resid");
```

**Sidenote: The way you are appending parameters to the query, your code is susceptible to SQL injection attacks! Consider using PreparedStatement.**

Comment: Yes i should implement the cose With preparedStatement! Anyway, in my web application when someone books a room automatically in hotel_booking is increment the value resid, it’s an integer value. Off course the user insert also all the data. Now I want create a bottom to delete all the line

Comment: Change your hidden field to "resid".